# change background-color on tablerow selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of tables as `partialViews` which are loaded in using ajax.

now I want to write a global function that when someone clicks on a `tablerow`, the `background-color` turns orange, and when selecting a different `tablerow` the old one turns white again and the new one turns orange.

so I wrote this at the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table tbody tr").on('click', function () {
            var selected = $(this).hasClass("selectedTableRow");
            $("table tbody tr").removeClass("selectedTableRow");
            if (!selected)
                $(this).addClass("selectedTableRow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

but it's not being reached at all, `console.logs` or `alerts` that I've placed in that function are not being fired. Why not?

btw my tables all have a standard setup

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating tables dynamically so bind click event using document with `.on`, see below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click',"table tr", function () {
            var selected = $(this).hasClass("selectedTableRow");
            $("table tr").removeClass("selectedTableRow");
            if (!selected)
                $(this).addClass("selectedTableRow");
        });
    });
```

Comment: that fixed it, thanks! I forgot that was also an option.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', "table tr", function () {
        $("table tr").removeClass("selectedTableRow");
        $(this).addClass("selectedTableRow");
    });
});
```